# Как подключить libcurl как статическую библиотеку в MSVS 2017?

Tags: c++

Загрузил [libcurl](https://github.com/curl/curl.git), октрыл *Command Prompt for VS 2017*, зашел в папку winbuilds и сделал nmake релиз версии, все прошло успешно, дальше создал новый WinApi проект и добавил в него папку curl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
#include "windows.h"

#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "curl/libcurl_a.lib")
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
 size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
 return written;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
 PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow) {

  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

  // curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  CURL *curl;
  FILE *fp;
  CURLcode res;
  const char *url = "http://www.google.com";
  char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\file.txt";
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

91 ошибка:

> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___WSAFDIsSet@8 referenced in function _Curl_poll..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl_a.lib")` и добавить путь к директории где лежит библиотеки в настройках проекта -> линкер

Comment: @NewView не помогло

Comment: Пути к библиотеки проверьте, и никому в начало файла, там где функция main